# What should be the value of jobs in flutter test -j, --concurrency=<jobs>?

Tags: flutter, testing, concurrency

I am trying to run my flutter test faster by running it concurrently.

This is my flutter doctor output.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale en-SG)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.1.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

I find this argument after running `flutter test --help`

```
-j, --concurrency=<jobs> | The number of concurrent test processes to run. This will be ignored when running integration tests. (defaults to "10")
```

I compare the time it takes to run all the flutter tests. In total, I am running 3000 independent tests.

```
flutter test // jobs = 10 (default value), finishes in 30 min.
flutter test -j 6 // jobs = 6, finishes in 17 min.
flutter test -j 4 // jobs = 4, finishes in 20 min.
```

The conclusion is running less jobs is faster than the default 10 jobs.

I assume that the number depends on the number of CPU cores available on your machine. My machine uses Processor 6-Core Intel Core i7, hence 10 is slower than 4 because my machine has only 6 cores.

Does it mean the optimum value of `jobs` should be the number of cores? Is there a way to determine the value of `jobs` to run in the flutter test?